# How can I generate arbitrary object property names in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way of creating a JavaScript object with varying property names. Something like this.

Imagine me getting the values from an array

```
var arraywithpropValues  = ["property=propertyValue, value=value"];
```

I want to create an object like

```
Object {property: "propertyValue", value: "value"}
```

Remember the **property** and **value** in the array can change anytime.

Is this possible?

Comment: `var o = {}; o[Math.random()] / Math.random()`? I don't know what you are asking...

Comment: Question might need some clarifications but you might want to take a look at AutoFixrure Libraries like: https://github.com/jcteague/autofixturejs

Comment: Why is `arraywithpropValues` even an array?

Comment: So you want a sort of live mapping from the array members to the object properties/values, so that when the array changes, the object updates?

Comment: Yes @squint exactly

Comment: Then update your question. It's really unclear. Still don't know if there are multiple objects or just one.

Comment: Just one object

Comment: I get a list of   ["property=propertyValue, value=value"] values

Comment: Can the length of the Array change too? And if so, should the object reflect those changes?

Comment: then convert them to objects

Comment: @IsaacChambers Read the tooltip on the downvote button: “This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful”. Your question doesn’t show any research effort and it is not clear.

Comment: yes the lenght can change

Comment: Thank @Xufox, will keep that in mind

Comment: @IsaacChambers Can you show an example of what the resulting object should look like when there is more than one string in `arraywithpropValues`?

Comment: Unless someone else has another idea, I think you may need to use [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to do this, which requires ES6. Aside from some sort of polling, that is.

Comment: So you don't actually want the object to update if/when the array changes; you just want to know how to use any value as the property name.

Comment: Yep. That was it. Sorry If i phrased my question wrong. Someone got it.

Comment: No problem. Remember to google first. This gets asked pretty frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are associative arrays. You can assign to a variable property name like so:

```
var name  = "foo";
var value = "bar";

object[name] = value;
```

I'll leave the string parsing of `arraywithpropValues` to you.